# Can somebody help me in Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button, android-intent

I created a wallpapers and ringtones app. 
Wallpapers and Ringtones are 2 buttons.

These 2 buttons open each other a new page. 
In the wallpapers page I have a button which I want to open a new page, but it doesn't work.

Below I pasted java and the manifest from android studio.

Main activity java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}


public void onButtonClicks(View c) {


    if (c.getId() == R.id.Bdisplay) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, display.class);
        startActivity(i);
        overridePendingTransition(R.animator.animation1, R.animator.animation2);
    }
}
 public void onClick (View v) {

     if (v.getId() == R.id.Bdisplay) {

         Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, display.class);
         startActivity(intent);
         overridePendingTransition(R.animator.animation1, R.animator.animation2);
     }
 }




public void onButtonClick(View x) {


    if (x.getId() == R.id.Bdisplay) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ringtone.class);
        startActivity(i);
        overridePendingTransition(R.animator.animation1, R.animator.animation2);
    }

}
```

ringtone java code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ringtone extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ringtone);

}

display(the name for wallpapers) java code:


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class display extends Activity
{


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display);

  }
}
```

And the java code for the new page:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class newpage extends Activity {

@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


  }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".display"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".ringtone"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".newpage"></activity>




</application>

</manifest>
```

What is am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are all the time launching the same Activity (MainActivity) when you click the button. Replace in your intent MainActivity.class and put the activity you want to launch.

Comment: So what I have to change in MainActivity? Can you write the java code?

Answer (score 0):

I have some suggestions for you:

- Always name Activities with capital letter and camelcase: NewPage instead of newpage and Ringtone instead of ringtone. this helps you with variables/activities & methods identifications.
- Calling an OnClick method use an explicit way.

Do like this:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        //do stuffs here
    }
});`
```

than yes, you always call the same class, probably this is why it doesn't work ;)

EDIT: to fix the problem try this:

in your Activities u have two buttons which send users to ringtones or wallpapers. Imagine they are called WallpaperButton and RingtoneButton; both in the activity called MainActivity, this activity should look like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnRingtone, btnWallpaper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnRingtone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.RingtoneButton);
        btnWallpaper = (Button) findViewById(R.Id.WallpaperButton);

        btnRingtone.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //Call the ringtone activity as "RingtoneActivity"
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RingtoneActivity.class);
                StartActivity(i);
            }
        });`

        btnWallpaper.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //Call the wallpaper activity as "WallpaperActivity"
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WallpaperActivity.class);
                StartActivity(i);
            }
        });`
    }
}
```

With this code in your mainactivity if an user clicks on the button wallpaper, he goes to wallpaper activity, if he clicks on button ringtone he goes to ringtone activity.

Do the same with the NewPageActivity. If you have trouble on how to create "SetOnClickListener" look [here for an example](https://uwudamith.wordpress.com/2012/05/19/how-to-use-onclicklistener-in-android/).

If you have troubles or questions feel free to ask :)

Comment: Can you be more explicit? What I have to change?